# How to Include 3rd Party SDK's inside an iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdk, cocoapods

I'm building an SDK that provides intensive Media handling and Client-Server communications. It requires RESTful Networking, Lazy image Loading & Cache management that includes Abstract Data all type of images like animated gifs.

Bottom line is that I Need to use certain Open-source Frameworks in order to deliver this SDK in this decade...

I've seen that Apple strongly discourages building "Umbrella Frameworks" and yet I Need to use these 3rd parties.

How do you set up an SDK to be able to use a dependency manager like Cocoapods and still abides by an SDK "Best Practices"?

I'm really stuck here I hope someone can shed some light on this and hopefully point me to some examples that include a .podspec file that manages this properly.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial, If you have any dependency that must be in your Pod you have to specify it in your .podspec

https://www.raywenderlich.com/99386/create-cocoapod-swift